# Join a GenericRelation and limit the result to latest in django

Tags: sql, django

Ok, tricky django query question...
I have a model to store emails which is connected (via a generic relation) to several other models (i.e. Participate). I do that, because in my application i send out many emails which are associated to different models and want to have them in one place (the email model).

```
class Participate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mails = GenericRelation(Email)

class Email(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    message = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
```

Now i want to query all datasets from Participate with the latest Email joint if there is one.
In SQL (database is postgres) this would look like:

```
select * from participate 
left join (
select distinct on (object_id) * from email
    WHERE email.content_type_id=26 
    order by object_id, created_at desc
) as most_recent_invitation
on most_recent_invitation.object_id = participate.id
```

This works fine with the latest email joined if there is one.

```
|----------------|------------------|----------|------------------|
| Participate.id | Participate.name | Email.id | Email.created_at |
|----------------|------------------|----------|------------------|
|    1           |    name1         |    1     |   2019-02-20     |
|----------------|------------------|----------|------------------|
|    2           |    name2         |    3     |   2019-02-18     |
|----------------|------------------|----------|------------------|
|    3           |    name3         |          |                  |
|----------------|------------------|----------|------------------|
|    4           |    name4         |          |                  |
|----------------|------------------|----------|------------------|
```

However i don't know how to do that with Django ORM and without custom SQL code. Any ideas?

Comment: I do have knowledge gap about `GenericForeignKey` and `GenericRelation` so i am not able to do any kind of help but i would like to thank you, you asked a very well organized question. A lot to learn from it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little rusty with Django so this is the closets I could get:

```py
Participate.objects.annotate(
    latest=Max('mails__created_at')
).order_by('-latest')
```

The resulting query being:

```sql
SELECT "related_participate"."id", "related_participate"."name", 
MAX("related_email"."created_at") AS "latest"
 FROM "related_participate" LEFT OUTER JOIN "related_email" ON 
   ("related_participate"."id" = "related_email"."object_id" AND
   ("related_email"."content_type_id" = 8)) 
  GROUP BY "related_participate"."id", "related_participate"."name" ORDER BY "latest" DESC
```

**UPDATE AFTER MORNING COFFEE**

It turns out that you can use `F` expressions in `annotate`:

```py
 Participate.objects.annotate(          
     latest=Max('mails__created_at'),       
     email_id=F('mails__id'),               
     email_created_at=F('mails__created_at')
 ).order_by('-latest')
```

and the SQL would be:

```sql
SELECT "related_participate"."id", "related_participate"."name", 
       MAX("related_email"."created_at") AS "latest", 
       "related_email"."id" AS "email_id", 
       "related_email"."created_at" AS "email_created_at" 
 FROM "related_participate" LEFT OUTER JOIN "related_email" 
 ON ("related_participate"."id" = "related_email"."object_id" 
 AND ("related_email"."content_type_id" = 8)) 
 GROUP BY "related_participate"."id", 
          "related_participate"."name",
          "related_email"."id", 
          "related_email"."created_at" 
 ORDER BY "latest" DESC
```

I think that covers your case.

Comment: Cool, that works! But it does not give the corresponding email object back or the other fields of the latest email (eg email.id).
I now found the subquery expression in django which lets you annotate specific field from a subquery: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

`newest = Email.objects.filter(object_id=OuterRef('id'), content_type_id=26).order_by('-created_at')
qs=Participate.objects.filter(recruitment__id=1).annotate(newest_email=Subquery(newest.values('id')[:1]))`

This is also doing the work, but again returns just one field..

Comment: @Cornelius I updated my post, let me know if it solves your use case now